# How to interpret the coefficients in a time varying linear regression model?

Tags: time-series, interpretation, time-varying-covariate, dlm

How do I interpret the coefficients in a time varying linear regression model (in particular theta2).

[image]

Formula from the book “Dynamic Linear Models with R”

As I understand, at time t theta2 is the expected effect of X on Y, when increasing X by 1 unit. To understand the general/overall effect of X on Y for all time points however, should I express the effect X on Y as an average effect/look at its distribution?